# PMS5003 connector type

Tags: connector

Could you be so kind to provide me with type of connector from this picture ? It's for PMS5003 particle sensor.

- Connector has 8 pins
- Distance between pins is roughly 1mm (sorry, don't have caliper)
- Width is 11 mm
- Thickness is 2 mm

Better pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are thousands of similar connectors of that sort. You have to measure the pitch of the pins and the width and thickness of the connector housing.

Comment: Please measure the pitch (center-to-center distance between contacts) and post it.  Please take photos with better focus, and perhaps different angles.

Comment: And throw in a ruler beside the connector for scale

Comment: Looks closer to 1.25mm or .050" to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the housing has two keys on both ends, not on top as for some other housings. So it looks like the Molex 0510210800 [PicoBlade series](https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/picoblade-51021-series/13170), with crimp connectors.